# Counting elements based on three criteria located in two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I wanted to ask you if there is a way to perform a count by applying formulas directly, without having to resort to the filter option, through the COUNTIF or COUNTIFS function.

From two criteria found in column A ("ENROLLED"; "ENROLLED -ACADEMICALLY COMPLETED"), I would like to know how many of them meet the "Paid" criteria found in Column C

[image: example]

I appreciate your collaboration

Psdt: I am using Office 365 version

In the attached link, you will find the book with the data of the example shown in the image.

[Example.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nxq02qxGWC1npnqduUPWPaQnvTFrw45o/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The following formula will return the number of "enrolled" + "enrolled-academically completed" that meet the "paid" criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "ENROLLED", C:C, "Paid")+COUNTIFS(A:A, "ENROLLED -ACADEMICALLY COMPLETED", C:C, "Paid")
```

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for your valuable collaboration, it has been very useful for me.
A big hug

Answer (score 1):

You may also use Sumproduct function.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="ENROLLED")*(C:C="Paid")+(A:A="ENROLLED -ACADEMICALLY COMPLETED")*(C:C="Paid"))`

[image]

Comment: Appreciated @Emily, thank you for your contribution, your help has been very useful. A big hug from afar